# Custom font with textures renders without textures in headings

Tags: html, css, fonts

I don't know how much info I should provide - code snippets, tools used, working environment - but here goes.

I am working on a website in React and I used `@font-face` to import self-hosted custom fonts. The font that I use for `p` works perfectly, but the font that I am using for headings (`h1, h2, etc.`) has a texture applied to it and the texture does not render properly.

For example, I have a `nav ul li a` element where the font appears as it should (don't know why):
example screenshot:
[image: example screenshot]

But for some reason, all `h1, h2`, etc. elements that use the same font, display it without the texture.
example screenshot:
[image: example screenshot]

Has anyone had a similar problem or even better, know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What other styling do you have written for your h1, h2 elements? I'm wondering if there's some conflict somewhere.

Comment: Share the code for @font-face. And how you have applied it.

Comment: Also in browser dev tools check what font gets applied on those elements. Share a screenshot may be.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/9OXlmV This is all the CSS code that I have that targets headings. @SanishJoseph

Comment: @SanishJoseph Both elements (nav ul li a and h1 and other headings) have one and the same applied to them.

Comment: From your screenshots I can see the difference only in the color. Did you check developer tool in your browser to see the difference?

Comment: @SanishJoseph Yeah, but turns out that the issue was much simpler. The font-style needed to be set as bold, not normal. The font does not work properly for headings with the normal style.

Comment: I saw your answer. I had a thought on that but didn't expect that could be the issue. Usually we attach different font files for bold italic etc.

Comment: @SanishJoseph My paragraph font has versions for italics, bold, normal, etc., but I was never planning on using italics for my heading... so I never bothered to check or include such options, but it turned out that the textured font only has one style - bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried many troubleshooting solutions - converting font files, trying different CSS rendering, etc. options, adding unicode-range, color options, etc. - but it turns out that all I needed to do was to swap `font-weight:normal;` with`font-weight:bold;`.

Now the font displays with textures not just for the `nav ul li a` elements but also for all headings. :)

I was overthinking the whole issue.